# How to access dynamic variable from another function if I don't want use class?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have 2 function are train function and logreg function, the main function is train that run logreg function inside it.

When i am executing train function it give me error,

```
NameError: name 'clf_hyper' is not defined
```

I think that i don't get `clf_hyper` variable that result in logreg function,

***Logreg function,***

```
from sklearn import model_selection

def logreg(clf,xtrain, ytrain):

    # define a grid of parameter
    # this can be a dictionary or a list of
    # dictionaries
    param_grid = {
        #"solver": ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag', 'saga'],
        #"penalty": ['none', 'l1', 'l2', 'elasticnet'],
        "C": [100, 10]
    }

    # initialize grid search
    model = model_selection.GridSearchCV(
        estimator = clf,
        param_grid = param_grid,
        scoring = "accuracy",
        verbose = 10,
        n_jobs = 1
    )

    # fit the model and extract best score
    model.fit(xtrain, ytrain)

    best_parameters = model.best_estimator_.get_params()
    for param_name in sorted(param_grid.keys()):
        print(f"\t{param_name}: {best_parameters[param_name]}")

    # initialize model with best_estimator_
    clf_hyper = model.best_estimator_
```

***Train function,***

```
import argparse
import os

import config
#import model_dispatcher
#import vectorizer_dispatcher
import dispatcher
import use_function
import hyperparameter

import pandas as pd
import joblib

from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

def run(fold, model, vectorizer):
    #read the training data
    df = pd.read_csv(config.TRAINING_FILE)

    # applying clean_text to Revies column
    df.loc[:, 'Review'] = df.Review.apply(use_function.clean_text)

    # training data is where kfold is not equal to provided fold
    # also, note that we reset the index
    df_train = df[df.kfold != fold].reset_index(drop=True)

    # validation data is where kfold is equal to provided fold
    df_test = df[df.kfold == fold].reset_index(drop=True)

    # initialize CountVectorizer with NLTK,s word_tokenize
    # function as tokenizer
    vectorizer = dispatcher.vectorizers[vectorizer]

    #fit count_vec on training data reviews
    vectorizer.fit(df_train.Review)

    #transform training and validation data reviews
    xtrain = vectorizer.transform(df_train.Review)
    xtest = vectorizer.transform(df_test.Review)

    ytrain = df_train.Rating

    # initialize model
    clf = dispatcher.models[model]

    #initialize hyperparameter if you want use
    # if not just give # sign in
    hyperparameter.logreg(clf,xtrain,ytrain)

    #return clf value from hyperparameter function
    #return clf_hyper


    #fit the model on training data reviews and Rating
    clf_hyper.fit(xtrain, df_train.Rating)

    # make prediction on test data
    # threshold for predictions is 0.5
    preds = clf_hyper.predict(xtest)

    #calculate accuracy
    accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(df_test.Rating, preds)

    print(f"Fold={fold}")
    print(f"Accuracy = {accuracy}")
    print("")

    # save the model
    joblib.dump(clf,os.path.join(config.MODEL_OUTPUT, "dt_{fold}.bin")
    )
```

so hows to get variabel clf_hyper in logreg function that i will use in train function if i don't want to use class? Thankyou

Comment: Why do you define these as function local variables in the first place? Why not ``return`` the value?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i don’t know how to return value in this case

Comment: Do you know how to ``return`` a value *in general*? What is unclear to you about returning this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try (if possible ?) to return the variabel clf_hyper directly from the function Logreg(). You could then get the value of clf_hyper by calling the function.

```
def logreg(clf, xtrain, ytrain):
    ...
    return clf_hyper
def run(fold, model, vectorizer):
    ...
    #return clf_hyper and exec the func
    return hyperparameter.logreg(clf,xtrain,ytrain)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to do it (i don't recommend) you can define clf_hyper as global variable

```
def logreg(clf,xtrain, ytrain):
    global clf_hyper
```